# php search string in encoded json

Tags: php, json

I want to search a particular string like "Booking Time" in encoded json object and want to print,

please check with encoded json example:-

```
{"1":["Booking Time","08-Oct-2017 23:18","Booking ID","ATO055GMEUZ"]}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Where is your proof of research and an attempt to solve?  You want to search for the value and do what exactly.

Comment: i'm very new to php and i don't know how to search value in encoded json.
i need code in php to search value from encoded json

Answer (score 0):

You need to format your JSON like below:-

```
{
  "1": {
    "Booking Time": "08-Oct-2017 23:18",
    "Booking ID": "ATO055GMEUZ"
  }
}
```

You can convert from json to array and do a loop to search.

`$json = json_decode($str);`

Comment: I'm getting json encoded in this format = {"1":["Booking Time","08-Oct-2017 23:18","Booking ID","ATO055GMEUZ"]}

Comment: i need code for master search if i want to search "Booking Time" in encoded json. it should show result "Booking Time"

Comment: please check with link http://www.webcyclomedia.com/agent/flight/view/testFlight.php

Comment: @HarshadPatil You don't need to reformat sourse string `$arr = json_decode($str, true); print_r($arr);`

Comment: @splash58 it is already formatted, only I need a code for master search which can search a particular value and display output.... example if I'm searching booking id in it, it will display booking id.

Comment: @HarshadPatil Can you work with usual array? I wrote above the code, making usual php array from the sourse string

Comment: @splash58 the format you posted is different from the format which i posted

Comment: @HarshadPatil This is not my answer, I have posted only code in comment. Use your string

Comment: @splash58 Okay i will explain you in details.
http://www.webcyclomedia.com/agent/flight/view/testFlight.php
go to above link and try to upload PDF. it will read the PDF and convert into Json.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161636/discussion-between-harshad-patil-and-splash58).